Oauth2 authentication on ASP .Net core API server
I'm trying to implement OAuth2 authentication on my API server written in ASP.NET Core. I have registered my application on Azure and I have the secret, clientId, tenantId, and scope available.

I configured the authentication with the following code in the Program.cs file:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

I am able to generate the authentication bearer token using Postman.
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "api://************/resources",
    "expires_in": 3975,
    "ext_expires_in": 3975,
    "access_token": "fsdfdklfnsldknfslkdnl..."
}

However, I want to configure Swagger to test my APIs. Therefore, I have added the following code:
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.EnableAnnotations();
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "bearer"
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "Bearer",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            Array.Empty<string>()
        }
    });
});

Any request I try to make through Swagger (after entering the bearer token) results in a 404 error (but I think it's a redirect from the 401 error).
I am new to ASP.NET Core programming and it’s not clear to me whether the error is in the authentication configuration or in Swagger.

I'm not very sure what trouble you are facing as it's 404 error. Could you please help check whether this case could help you or not?
